# Integrating iAd into an existing Cocos2D app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How would I integrate iAd into an existing Cocos2D game?

Comment: You're going to have to get a whole lot more specific if you want to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually done it before.  But here is a link that might help on intergating UIKit and Cocos2D.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit.  If that is not what you are looking for you are going to have to give more detail.